# Why do some questions have very low views even with a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

This question ([Ganglia: How to encrypt metrics in transit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747167/ganglia-how-to-encrypt-metrics-in-transit)) has only 17 views when I'm writing this:

> This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation from mykola
>   ending in 13 hours.

That means, today is the last day after starting bounty.

He has set bounty because of,

> This question has not received enough attention.

But I think even with bounty, that question has not received enough attention.

Why that happens? And please can you explain the programming logic behind a bounty?

Comment: Is that question even programming related? Just a single (niche) tag might also be a reason few views.

Comment: Moreover, this questions seems to be really broad. It there was not an open bounty on it, I really think it would be closed.

Comment: It's also sitting at -8 (-9/+1). I'm not sure how much the question score affects whether people actually look at a bounty question but that probably isn't helping.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [honk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355460/why-some-question-has-very-low-views-even-with-bountry#comment506542_355460) already noted it seems a bit of a niche tag, in a highly specific technology. There are so far only 149 questions asked in that tag and [the top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ganglia/topusers) are still in an *everyone can win* battle.

The technology the question asks about is  for *a scalable distributed system monitor tool for high-performance computing systems such as clusters and grids*. I don't think many users work with that as opposed to, for example, Java, C/C++ or Regex.

The first point made by honk might be related as well. It could well be that the solution to the question is on the edge of what a developer does and were a system- or network engineer would take over. But only an expert in that tag can tell for sure.

Lastly the question itself is maybe a bit terse. Had the OP included a setting they found or tried (just including what you search for can be of help), the users that could answer the question would have known where to extent on the knowledge of the OP.

Bountied questions become active when the bounty is started (they will go to the front of the active tab of the tag) and they might be bumped to the homepage but on Stack Overflow there are so many posts competing that it won't stay there for long (less then 30 minutes if you're lucky). Beyond that the question will only be listed on the [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured) tab.

Keep in mind that a bounty is just like an ad in the newspaper. You pay upfront to have your ad printed on page 3 but you have no guarantee your ad will be seen by your potential customers, let alone if it leads to a higher conversion. if your sales stay at 0 you can't go ask for a refund.

Comment: Thanks. In last sentence I asked something like this. According to FAQ, "The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the homepage Featured tab for 7 days." Is it only? I thought it comes to active tab or hot tab in randoms time( I mean one time per day)... Seems like I am wrong.

Comment: @DonkeyKingandDonkeyKing added a paragraph about that

Comment: Liked the comparison to an ad and sales without refund.

Comment: @rene Thanks. I read it. Then what is the difference between offering 50 bounty and 500 bounty.

Comment: No difference, @DonkeyKing. It costs 50 for the first ad/bounty, 100 for the second, and so on, all the way up to 500. Repeated exposures get increasingly more expensive.

Comment: @DonkeyKingandDonkeyKing A higher bounty means higher views, at least. More people will be interested in taking at least a cursory glance at the question if there's a 500-rep bounty than if there's only a 50-rep bounty.